# How can I pass parameters through an OAuth authentication so that my callback or controller can use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, devise, omniauth

I am using OAuth to a provider (LinkedIn).

I want to be able to pass parameters so that when someone signs-up, I can add some additional values at the time the new User is created (I am using Devise).

But how do I do that?

It looks like the link goes to the provider, which then makes a callback to my application.  How can I pass parameters from that link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way to do this is to set the parameters in the session, then access them in the callback.

In your action that redirects to the provider:

```
session[:additional] = additional_data_hash
```

In the action that handles the callback from the provider:

```
data = session.delete(:additional)
```

Use `delete` to ensure your session remains small for subsequent requests.

Comment: I think the action that does the redirect is in devise....how do I handle that then?

Comment: okay, so I think I add it as a session, let it go to the call back and I use it....

Comment: I would really love it if someone could answer this question correctly.  Session is a hack around the actual issue addressed.

Answer (score 18):

If you add `GET` style params to the authentication url they will be available in the callback via the Rails `request.env` object under the `omniauth.params` key. For example

If you authenticate via:

```
link_to "Log In", "/auth/linkedin?foo=bar"
```

In the controller method mapped to `GET /auth/:provider/callback` you will have:

```
request.env['omniauth.params'] == { "foo" => "bar" }
```

Answer was a bit late, but I hope it helps someone.

Comment: the thing is the bar will be new everytime, foo will be same, how is that possible? I want bar to be dynamic

Comment: I was attempting to use this for NetDocuments authentication, but it caused an invalid_grant response.

Answer (score -1):

Notice that if you're using ng-token-auth then you can pass parameters to [$auth.authenticate](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth#authauthenticate), and these will be used when creating the User model.
For example:

`$auth.authenticate('github', {params: {favorite_color: 'green'})`